Multer error is not returned to the frontend
I'm working on handling course lecture uploads using Multer in my Node.js project. My problem is that when Multer throws an error (e.g., file size exceeds the limit or unsupported file type), the error message is logged correctly on the backend but isn't being returned to the frontend.
Here's my route and controller code:
router.post('/:id', isLoggedIn, authorizedRoles, addLectureToCourseById);

export const addLectureToCourseById = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        upload(req, res, async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error while adding lecture', err.message); //working perfectly
                return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message }); 
                // Unable to send this error back to the frontend.
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error paaji', error);
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
};

The Multer configuration:
const upload = multer({
    limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }, //50GB
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'uploads/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);

        const allowedExtensions = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.webp'];

        if (!allowedExtensions.includes(extension.toLowerCase())) {
            console.log('Unsupported file type:', extension);
            return cb(new Error('Unsupported file type'), false);
        }

        cb(null, true);
        console.log('File is valid and uploading...');
    }
}).single('lecture');

The isLoggedIn and authorizedRoles are as follows:
export const isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { token } = req.cookies;
        if (!token) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                success:false,
                message:'Unauthenticated, Please login.'
            })
        }

        const userDetails = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = userDetails;
        next();

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error is this', e);
        return res.status(400).json({
            success:false,
            message:e.message
        })
    }
}
export const authorizedRoles = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user.role === "USER") {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "You don't have permission to access this"
        })
    }
    next();
}

I have tried everything but unable to get the error back at the frontend. Can Somebody help ?

show the frontend code which is making the request
